# user name and number hit on sharepoint site

Tags: site

Can someone provide me any solution which help to check number of user hit and user name who visited on selected sharepoint site. Like as of now I only want for site "http://sharepoint.question.aspx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/use-reports-to-measure-site-performance-and-usage-HA010174136.aspx#BM6

Just open this on whatever site you would like to have the diagnostics on.

Answer (score 1):

To see usage pattern of a site, you have can go for Web Analytics : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

If you want further details, like how many visits were made by a single user, you may have to read ISS Logs: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-SharePoint-Flavored-5b03f323/view/Discussions#content